# Youtube Chromeless Player with Custom HTML player and native HTML controls

Tags: html5-video, youtube-javascript-api

I have custom player which plays videos from my server. The controls are native html player but I have custom tracking and ad serving mechanism.

Now I am adding support to integrate YouTube with the player with ChromelessPlayer. Can I use default HTML player controls with chromeless player?